# Custom UIProgressView style

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, progress, uiprogressview

I am trying to customize my UIProgressView. I would like it to look like the third one down on the image:

[image]

Please can you tell me how I could acheive this.

Comment: I have only tried with PDProgressView: [progressView setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f/255.0f green:176.0f/255.0f blue:224.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f]];
    [progressView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:48.0f/255.0f green:48.0f/255.0f blue:48.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f]];

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out OCProgress: http://www.obsessivecode.com/projects/ocprogress/

It is very customizable, from width to height to bar color to back color to border color.

Comment: You mean is this code app-store safe? 100% safe for the app store.

Comment: @DanielAmitay can you provide some sample code on how to use OCProgress? I know this was over a year ago but I'm new to iOS. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at this: https://github.com/PascalW/PDColoredProgressview ?

Comment: Yes. The background colour won't actually work on a UIProgressViewDefault progressView.